# Different URL Load with shouldStartLoadWithRequest

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, uiwebviewdelegate

i am currently using `http://something.com` this link inside the uiwebview for my ios app. In this dummy website there is another link. I wanna open native ios camera screen after clicking this link. Right now i am able to open cam only for `http://something.com` this url. But i need to open the cam by clicking another link inside this `http://something.com`. When i click the other link url is changing to ``http://something.com\webapp`. So how can i make it work? Any ideas?

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSURL *url = request.URL;
NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;

NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString:@"http://something.com"];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
   [self showCamera]; //camera starts
    return YES;
} else {
    return NO;
    }
```

Comment: You can check the other link is present or not using "[urlString  containsString:@"your other url"]".If it is present you can open camera."containsString" is available from iOS 8.0

Comment: Can you give me an example how will i open another link `http://something.com/webapp` that located inside  `http://something.com` by using containsString? @sanman

Comment: I meant you can check string using "containsString" that you are being redirected to.Instead of using NSRange.i.e after clicking on button.Check richmond's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
if ([request.URL.absoluteString containsString:@"webapp"]) {
   [self showCamera];
   return NO;
} else {
   return YES;
}
```